# Does RISC-V mandate two's complement or one's complement signedness, or is it implementation-determined?

Tags: twos-complement, riscv, instruction-set, ones-complement

I have looked through the ISA spec and searched the internet for the answer to this, but I could not find it.

In the RISC-V ISA, should negative numbers be represented with one's complement or two's complement?  Or, is this decision left to implementors?

The reason I ask is that I am writing an RV32I simulator, and this would affect how I store negative numbers in the simulated memory, for example.

Answer (score 6):

The RISC-V architecture requires twos-complement integer arithmetic.  This can be most directly seen from the fact that it specifies a single addition instruction, not a pair of signed and unsigned addition instructions.  In twos-complement arithmetic, signed and unsigned addition are the same operation; in ones-complement (and sign-magnitude) they are not the same.

It appears to me, skimming the architecture manual, that the authors considered the choice of twos-complement integer arithmetic *too obvious to bother mentioning.*  There hasn't been a CPU manufactured in at least 25 years that used anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The [user-level ISA manual](http://riscv.org/specifications/) (page 13) notes that bitwise `NOT rd, rs1` may be performed by `XORI rd, rs1, -1`, which would imply two's complement, if I see things correctly: XORing with the one's complement of -1 would not invert the least significant bit, while it would work correctly in two's complement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the RISC-V instruction set architecture (ISA) mandates [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

> The base integer instruction sets use a two’s-complement representation for signed integer values.

(Section 1.3 RISC-V ISA Overview, page 4, [The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual. Volume I](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual), 2019-06-08, ratified)

> General purpose registers x1–x31 hold values that various instructions interpret as a collection of Boolean values, or as two’s complement signed binary integers or unsigned binary integers.

(Section 2.1 Programmers' Model for Base Integer ISA, page 13, [The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual. Volume I](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual), 2019-06-08, ratified)